# How to set compatibility settings in a clickonce deployed application

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

I have an application I am publishing through clickonce. It does not respond well to having difference display scale settings in windows. This can be fixed by going into the properties of the EXE file and changing the DPI settings. However I am struggling to find a way to deploy the application with these settings on for all users. Any help will be great thank you! I can't post images because I dont have enough reputation. To find my solution though right click an application -> propertes -> coompatibility -> Change high dpi settings. First checkbox

I have tried to search online and found one answer pertaining to windows 8 compatibility mode but I don't think it applies to my issue.

EDIT This is a winforms app

Comment: You mentioned in a comment under the (likely AI) answer that you can't upload images, but you *should* be able to.  You can't make them inline, but you should be able to upload and link to them at this point.  Another user will then (sometimes) edit the post to make it inline for you. Can you try again?